# curve integral - intersection between plane and sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am going to calculate the line integral
$$ \int_\gamma z^4dx+x^2dy+y^8dz,$$
where $\gamma$ is the intersection  of the plane $y+z=1$ with the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, $x \geq 0$, with the orientation given by increasing  $y$.

Since $\gamma$ is an intersection curve, I decided to use Stoke's theorem,  applied to  the vector field $(z^4,x^2,y^8)$ and an oriented surface $Y$ with  boundary $\gamma$. But how am I going to parametrize the surface so I can use it with Stoke's thoerem?

If I parametrize the surface by $(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))=(0,t,1-t),$ $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, I will get the normal vector $(0,0,0)$, but the normal vector is going to point upwards, I think.

Comment: I think it would be better to parametrize curve $\gamma$.

Comment: The paraametrization in my post was a parametrization of the surface with the intersecation curve as its boundary. I forgot to write that x,y and z satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2=<1$.

Comment: any hints? @nikita2

Comment: Hint: try parametrization for $\gamma$ like this
$$
x(t) = \cos t, \quad y(t) = \sin t, \quad z(t) = 1 - \sin t, \quad t\in[0,2\pi]. 
$$

Comment: It will be nice if you post your solution here. @Angelica

Comment: I will do it when I come home :)

Comment: @nikita2: i have tried with this parametrization but i am getting wrong answer. the right answer are: $$2/9 + (7*\pi)/(32\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: You can only used Stokes theorem when the domain of your line integral is a closed curve. That's not happening in this problems since you're requiring $x\geq 0$

Comment: The 2/9 part is coming from integrating along the straight line part of the intersection, I can see that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is another homework orphan.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection curve (an ellipse) is given by $x^2+2(y-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{2}$. It can be parametrized as $x=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cos t$, $y=\frac{1}{2}\sin t+\frac{1}{2}$, where $t\in[0,2\pi]$ (also don't forget z=1-y). Could you check all this and try to carry out the integration, and maybe show your work below?

Comment: How did you get the intersection curve ?

Edit:
I suppose you put z=1-y in the sphere ? i will post the solution when i am back from school. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the plane $\Pi\to(p-p_0)\cdot\vec n = 0$ and the sphere $S\to\|p\|=r$ the distance from $\Pi$ to the origin is calculated as $p_i$ where $p_i$ is the intersection point between $\Pi$ and the line $L\to p = \lambda \frac{\vec n}{\|\vec n\|}$ or $d=\lambda^* = \frac{p_0\cdot\vec n}{\|\vec n\|}$. The intersection $S\cap\Pi$ produces a circumference with radius $r_c = \sqrt{r^2-d^2}$. Now we can build a parameterized circumference representing the intersection $S\cap\Pi$ as

$$
C(\gamma) = p_i + \left(\vec s\sin\gamma +\vec t\cos\gamma\right)r_c
$$

with $\{\vec s, \vec t\}$ such that

$
\cases{
\vec t\cdot\vec n = 0\\
\vec t\times\frac{\vec n}{\|n\|}=\vec s\\
\|\vec t\|=1
}
$

NOTE

Here $p=(x,y,z),\ \vec n = (0,1,1)$ and $p_0=(0,0,1)$.
With $C(\gamma)$ we have $\{x(\gamma),y(\gamma),z(\gamma)\}$ and finalizing with

$$
 \int_{\gamma}\left( z^4(\gamma)\frac{dx}{d\gamma}+x^2(\gamma)\frac{dy}{d\gamma}+y^8(\gamma)\frac{dz}{d\gamma}\right)d\gamma
$$